# Make horizontal menu and its items centered

Tags: html, css

i am working on a menu and i want to keep it in center like that

[image]

but currently its like that. i tried lot of css tricks but nothing make it centered as i want so any one help me i will be very thankfull to you for that kind favour in advance.

[image]

here is my html

```
  <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Animals</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Funny</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Gifs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Mems</a></li>
                <li><a href="">TV</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Social Media</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Like A Boss</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Fail</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Demotivational</a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="">WTF</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Awesome</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>

            </ul>    
        </div>
```

here is my css

```
.nav-menu{
display: table;
width:570px;
}
.nav-menu ul{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
text-align:center;
margin: auto;
width: 570px;
}

.nav-menu ul li{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:25px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.nav-menu ul li a{

float:left;
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;
color:#9e9e9e;
font-size:11px;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu ul li a:hover{
display:block;
float:left;
margin:0;
text-decoration:underline;
color:#b8c5b2;
font-size:11px
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeh sure, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJKZE/1/). New CSS:

```
.nav-menu {
    width:570px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
}
.nav-menu ul {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    margin: auto;
    list-style:none;
}
.nav-menu ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
...
```

I've removed the `float:left` on your `.nav-menu ul li`, removed the width on your `.nav-menu ul` and moved the `text-align:center` to your `.nav-menu`.

**Update** I also removed the `display:table` as I imagine you added this as one of your tests, but it's simply unneeded.

Comment: @kwk.stack If that answer helped you, you should mark it with the green V "accept as answer" button.